# Drawing a grid in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

i have a 9x9 grid of buttons right now, and i would like to draw some lines between those buttons to separate them and make a 3x3 grid.

I tried my method in a JPanel in another window and it works fine, but i can't get it work in my JFrame alongside my buttons, as it draws nothing.
There is already some space between each button so we can see the line if it's there.

Thanks a lot for your future help.

Here is the code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonGrid extends JPanel{

JFrame frame=new JFrame();
int t = 9;

public ButtonGrid(){ //constructor
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(t, t, 3, 3));
    addButtons(frame, t);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true); 

}

@Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            int coord = i * 58;
            coord++;
            g.drawLine(coord, 0, coord, 58*9);
            g.drawLine(0, coord, 58*9, coord);
        }
    }
}

private void addButtons(JFrame frame, int t){
    JButton grid;
    for(int y=0; y<t; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<t; x++){
            grid=new JButton(x+","+y); //creates new button
            grid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(55,55));
            frame.add(grid); //adds button to grid

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonGrid();
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never draw directly on the JFrame as you're trying to do. This carries significant risk if you don't know what you're doing (for example you don't call the super's paint method and are inadvertently breaking the painting chain this way), and the images drawn won't show as they'll be covered by the opaque contentPane.

If you need to draw, do so in a JPanel that is then displayed inside the JFrame, but again as per my example below, there's no need to draw if all you want are black straight lines in a grid.

Use a GridLayout, and set some gaps into your layout. Understand that the 3rd and 4th parameters of the GridLayout constructor will give you the gaps. Then give the underlying JPanel a Color.BLACK background, and there you go: lines! For example with JTextFields:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SudokuMCVE extends JPanel {
    private static final int CLUSTER = 3;
    private static final int MAX_ROWS = 9;
    private static final float FIELD_PTS = 32f;
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color SOLVED_BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 2 * 1000;
    private JTextField[][] fieldGrid = new JTextField[MAX_ROWS][MAX_ROWS];

    public SudokuMCVE() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(CLUSTER, CLUSTER));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.setBackground(BG);
        JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[CLUSTER][CLUSTER];
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < panels[i].length; j++) {
                panels[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(CLUSTER, CLUSTER, 1, 1));
                panels[i][j].setBackground(BG);
                panels[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
                mainPanel.add(panels[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < fieldGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < fieldGrid[row].length; col++) {
                fieldGrid[row][col] = createField(row, col);
                int i = row / 3;
                int j = col / 3;
                panels[i][j].add(fieldGrid[row][col]);
            }
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JButton(new SolveAction("Solve")), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private JTextField createField(int row, int col) {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(2);
        field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        field.setFont(field.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, FIELD_PTS));

        return field;
    }

    private class SolveAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SolveAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                private int i = 0;
                private int j = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // MAX_ROWS is 9
                    if (i == MAX_ROWS) {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    if (j == MAX_ROWS) {
                        i++;
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    int number = (int) (MAX_ROWS * Math.random()) + 1;
                    fieldGrid[i][j].setBackground(SOLVED_BG);
                    fieldGrid[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(number));

                    j++;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SudokuMCVE mainPanel = new SudokuMCVE();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SudokuMCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Or with JButtons:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JPanelGrid extends JPanel {
    private static final int SML_SIDE = 3;
    private static final int SIDE = SML_SIDE * SML_SIDE;
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Dimension BTN_PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(80, 80);
    private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[SIDE][SIDE];

    public JPanelGrid() {
        setBackground(BG);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SML_SIDE, SML_SIDE, GAP, GAP));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        JPanel[][] smallPanels = new JPanel[SML_SIDE][SML_SIDE];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallPanels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < smallPanels[i].length; j++) {
                smallPanels[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(SML_SIDE, SML_SIDE));
                add(smallPanels[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            int panelI = i / SML_SIDE;
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                int panelJ = j / SML_SIDE;
                String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", j, i);
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(text);
                buttons[i][j].setPreferredSize(BTN_PREF_SIZE);
                smallPanels[panelI][panelJ].add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JPanelGrid mainPanel = new JPanelGrid();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPanelGrid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Which displays:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made these minimal modifications in your code,
- add buttons to panel (not to frame)
- set panel as frame's content pane
- change method `paint` with `paintComponent` and call firstly `super.paintComponent` in method body
- and change line coordinate calculations

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonGrid extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int t = 9;

    public ButtonGrid() { // constructor
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(t, t, 3, 3));
        addButtons(t);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
//      g.setColor(getBackground());
//      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                int coordx = getWidth() * i / 9;
                int coordy = getHeight() * i / 9;
                g.drawLine(coordx, 0, coordx, getHeight());
                g.drawLine(0, coordy, getWidth(), coordy);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addButtons(int t) {
        JButton grid;
        for (int y = 0; y < t; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < t; x++) {
                grid = new JButton(x + "," + y); // creates new button
                grid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(55, 55));
                add(grid); // adds button to grid

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh now i understand what i did wrong there, thank you !